# Extracting data from a dataframe with dictionaries in column elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I tried fetching the column to a list, and then getting the values, but did not happen. I need to preserve the NaN as well.
The column has a a structure -

```
df['geocoded_column']
0       {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-117.009178,...
1                                                     NaN
2                                                     NaN
3       {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-104.612123,...
4       {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-86.043072, ...
                              ...                        
2726    {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-87.879139, ...
2727    {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-95.266593, ...
2728    {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-92.317039, ...
2729    {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-83.017686, ...
2730    {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-91.528653, ...

df['geocoded_column'][0] - 
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-117.009178, 32.779435]}



I need to segregate it into the type - 
Latitude                        Longitude
-117.117.009178                32.779435
NaN                             NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for ya

```py
df['Latitude'] = [point['coordinates'][0] for point in df['geocoded_column']]
df['Longitude'] = [point['coordinates'][1] for point in df['geocoded_column']]
```

Comment: To avoid doing the comprehension twice: `df['Lat'], df['Lon'] = zip(*[d['coordinates'] for d in df['geocoded_column']])`

Comment: Doesn't handle NaNs

Comment: `df['Lat'], df['Lon'] = zip(*[(np.nan, np.nan) if pd.isna(d) else d['coordinates'] for d in df['geocoded_column']])`

Answer (score 2):

Check this , Nan values are controlled:

```
lat = []
lon = []
for x in df['geocoded_column']:
    if isinstance(x,dict):
        lat.append(x['coordinates'][0])
        lon.append(x['coordinates'][1])
    else:
        lat.append(np.nan)
        lon.append(np.nan)

df['latitude']=lat
df['longitude']=lon
```

Output:

```
                                     geocoded_column    latitude  longitude
0  {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-117.009178,... -117.009178      -33.0
1                                                NaN         NaN        NaN
2                                                NaN         NaN        NaN
3  {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-104.612123,... -104.612123      123.0
4  {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-86.043072, ...  -86.043072       24.0
```

Comment: This Worked for me! Thanks alot :)